# How to check whether the 'value' of a 'key' present in the JSONRequest body is empty or not using Java

Tags: java, json, isnull

I have a JSON Request with the body of a request containing three parameters. I need to check whether the 'value' for the 'key' is empty or not in the body of the JSON request. I'm trying this using java code. How can I check this condition in my code?

This is my JSON Request:

```
{
    "Details": [
        {
           "EmpId" : "123456",
           "DeptId" : "12345678",
           "Name" : "abc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please Note: I have two parameters that have integer values and one that has a String value.

Answer (score 0):

As you have a response in **JSONObject jsonObject**, you have to check for the **key** you are looking for, like this : 
`if(!jsonObject.isNull("EmpId")) {
}`

`jsonObject.isNull("key")` is the method used for checking whether the key is present or not. If the key is not present, this method returns true.
One thing to remember, this method only check whether the key is present in json object or not. If present, you can alternatively check for the value is empty or has some values. 
Then check for the value of that particular key like this : 
`String employeeId = jsonObject.getString("EmpId");`.

So you have to traverse like this : 
`if(!jsonObject.isNull("EmpId")) {
    String employeeId = jsonObject.getString("EmpId");
}`
Hope it will help you.

Comment: Just a small clarification, jsonObject.isNull("key")..Here, Can we use the 'key' of all data types irrespective of  integer/String/double values..Knowing this would be helpful.